# Adding Addtional Styles to GeoServer via Python

Tags: python, geoserver, sld, request

I am having difficulties in adding additional styles to GeoServer Layers using pythons Requests module.

The below code works perfectly up to the try block. It will successfully publish layer from an SQL Data Store as a WMS and I have tested this via QGIS.
But as soon as I run the code in the Try block the Layer is can no longer be found in the WMS getcapabilities_1.1.1.xml and I can’t access the layer via QGIS.

The Layer still exists if I go to the GeoServer GUI and it even has the correct Styles displaying in “Selected Styles” and if I go to Edit Layer>Publishing>Root Layer in Capabilities and select “Yes” on the radial buttons it will fix the problem. The layer will be available in QGIS and will display the correct symbology.

**Code**

```
for xmlCommand in xmlCommmands:
    xmlCommandSplit = xmlCommand.split('|')
    xmlLayer = xmlCommand.split('|')[0]
    featureTypeURL = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/OS_OpenData/datastores/OS_OpenData/featuretypes'
    headers = {'Content-type': 'text/xml', 'Accept': 'text/xml'}
    xmlInsert = '''
                <featureType>
                    <name>{}</name>
                </featureType>
            '''.format(xmlLayer)
    createRequest = requests.post(featureTypeURL, auth=auth, data=xmlInsert, headers=headers)
    if createRequest.status_code == 201:
        print("{} - Published".format(xmlLayer))
    else:
        print("\t{} - Not Published - CODE:{}".format(xmlLayer, createRequest.status_code))
        reason = createRequest.content.decode()
        parser.feed(reason)
    try:
        style = xmlCommand.split('|')[1]
        xmlStyle = '''
                <layer>
                    <styles>
                        {}
                        <workspace>OS_OpenData</workspace>
                    </styles>
                </layer>
               '''.format(str(style).lower())
        styleURL = 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/OS_OpenData:{}'.format(xmlLayer)
        headers = {'Content-type': 'text/xml', 'Accept': 'text/xml'}
        styleRequest = requests.put(styleURL, auth=auth, data=xmlStyle, headers=headers)
        if styleRequest.status_code == 200:
            print("{} - Style Set ".format(xmlLayer))
            reason = styleRequest.content.decode()
            parser.feed(reason)
        else:
            print("\t{} - Style Not Set - CODE:{} ".format(xmlLayer, styleRequest.status_code))
            reason = styleRequest.content.decode()
            parser.feed(reason)
    except IndexError:
        pass
```

Example xmlCommand:

```
bl_high_water_polyline_201910|<name>bl_high_water_polyline</name>
```

Here is a example of the URL: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/layers/OS_OpenData:bl_high_water_polyline_201910

Here is a example of the Payload:

```
<layer>
    <styles>
        <name>bl_high_water_polyline</name> 
        <workspace>OS_OpenData</workspace>
    </styles>
</layer>
```

Comment: can you add exactly what the URL you are sending to and what the payload is? I don't see where the SLD is uploaded

Comment: Sure, I have added example of the URL and Payload to the Question. I have allready upload the SLD to GeoServer. They are available under the "Data>Style" on the GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cracked it!

Basically, the issue was assigning the style to a workspace. After changing my SLD upload code, and the layer publishing code to remove reference to a workspace my code now works as intended.